# Changing Dependency Property doesn't cause Custom Control to re render when wanted

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, rerender

I've got a Custom Control defined as below, the Generic.xaml file only contains a template with a canvas called 'cvRoot' in it.

I cannot get the control to rerender itself properly when a one of the dependency properties changes. Whilst it may draw when I use it in an application, when I try and measure it, I always get a zero size back. This is incredibly frustrating as I need to get the size to align the control properly.

I've tried using FrameworkPropertyMetadata in the Dependency Property register method with the option set to AffectsRender, but this doesn't change what happens. I've also tried InvalidateVisual in the Callback for each property with no joy.

I'm really pulling my hair out here, any ideas?

```
namespace   GraphControls
{
    public class Marker :   Control
    {
        private Canvas cvRoot   =   null;
        private static Action   EmptyDelegate   =   delegate() { };

        static Marker()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Marker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Marker)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            cvRoot = GetTemplateChild("cvRoot") as Canvas;
        }



        protected   override void   OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);

            cvRoot.Children.Clear();

            // Text
            //
            TextBlock   tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text =   Text;
            tb.FontSize =   MarkerFontSize;
            tb.Foreground   =   TextColour;
            tb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

            // Background   Ellipse
            //
            Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
            el.Width = tb.DesiredSize.Height;
            el.Height   =   tb.DesiredSize.Height;
            el.Fill =   MarkerFill;

            // Add to   Canvas and reposition
            //
            cvRoot.Children.Add(el);
            cvRoot.Children.Add(tb);
            Canvas.SetLeft(tb, (el.Width / 2)   -   (tb.DesiredSize.Width   /   2));
            Canvas.SetTop(tb,   (el.Height / 2) -   (tb.DesiredSize.Height / 2));

            // Resize   the owning Canvas   so that external Measures   work
            //
            cvRoot.Width = el.Width;
            cvRoot.Height   =   el.Height;

        }

        public static   DependencyProperty TextProperty =   DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Marker),
                                        new PropertyMetadata("X",   new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGenericDependencyPropertyChanged)));
        public static   DependencyProperty MarkerFontSizeProperty   =   DependencyProperty.Register("MarkerFontSize",   typeof(double), typeof(Marker),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(12D,   new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGenericDependencyPropertyChanged)));
        public static   DependencyProperty MarkerFillProperty   =   DependencyProperty.Register("MarkerFill",   typeof(Brush), typeof(Marker),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGenericDependencyPropertyChanged)));
        public static   DependencyProperty TextColourProperty   =   DependencyProperty.Register("TextColour",   typeof(Brush), typeof(Marker),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGenericDependencyPropertyChanged)));

        public string   Text
        {
            get {   return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set {   SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public double   MarkerFontSize
        {
            get {   return (double)GetValue(MarkerFontSizeProperty); }
            set {   SetValue(MarkerFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush MarkerFill
        {
            get {   return (Brush)GetValue(MarkerFillProperty); }
            set {   SetValue(MarkerFillProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush TextColour
        {
            get {   return (Brush)GetValue(TextColourProperty); }
            set {   SetValue(TextColourProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnGenericDependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs   e)
        {
            ((Marker)d).Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render,    EmptyDelegate);
        }

        protected   override Size   MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            Size retval =   new Size();

            // Handle   the template not being called   yet
            //
            if (cvRoot !=   null)
            {
                cvRoot.Measure(constraint);
                retval = cvRoot.DesiredSize;
            }

            return retval;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: After coming at this from a different direction, I have found a workaround of sorts. If I call the InvalidateVisual method at the client end on the instance of the custom control that I am using before I do a measure, then it works. Its making me wonder if I need some way of letting the control finish what it is doing before trying to set another property. This is all speculation of course...

Comment: You should perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve with this control. Changing the child elements of the cvRoot Canvas during OnRender feels really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code example, it appears that you are using the wrong kind of control to extend. From the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> #### Benefits of Deriving from Control
>
> Consider deriving from Control instead of using the UserControl class
> if any of the following apply:
>
> •You want the appearance of your control to be customizable via the
> ControlTemplate.
>
> •You want your control to support different themes.
>
> #### Benefits of Deriving from UserControl
>
> Consider deriving from UserControl if all of the following apply:
>
> •You want to build your control similarly to how you build an
> application.
>
> •Your control consists only of existing components.
>
> •You don't need to support complex customization.

Therefore, I believe that you will have much more luck if you use a `UserControl` and declare your UI elements in XAML. However, if you are *sure* that you want to use a `CustomControl`, then you should define *all* of your UI elements in XAML in the `ControlTemplate` for your control in `generic.xaml`. They will all be rendered automatically then and you won't need to refresh anything manually.

Also, you shouldn't *really* be using the `OnRender` method to do what you could simply do in XAML. That's more often used for defining new graphics for a control that are not already available for use from other UI elements in WPF. Just create `DependencyProperties` and data bind to any properties that you want to control in the UI. On thing to note is that you'll have to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to access them from `generic.xaml` (assuming you have added the `GraphControls` XAML Namespace Prefix):

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding MarkerFill, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GraphControls:Marker}}}" />
```

Comment: I think you are probably right - I'm 3 weeks into WPF development, coming from a winforms background, so the learning curve is quite steep. I have a separate custom control which I am writing (a graph control) which is pretty much all taking place in the onRender event (as the Pluralsight tutorial says to do), it works fine as its very low level stuff. From this experience I'm going revamp the the new control (which is a simple marker for the graph to use) as a UserControl and see how that goes...